# React-bootstrap class styles don't apply

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm using react-bootstrap by importing react-bootstrap components, but class styles are not applied to elements for some reason, even though I can see that bootstrap classes are given to corresponding elements in the DOM. I use my own class for positioning, it doesn't override anything. Does anyone have any ideas what could be wrong? For example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {Alert} from 'react-bootstrap'

class Error extends Component {
render() {
const {errorText} = this.props
return (
  <Alert bsStyle="warning" className="error-container">
    <div className="error-msg">{errorText}</div>
  </Alert>
);
}
}
```

Comment: Did you add bootstrap style sheet somewhere, probably in `index` html file as described here https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started.html.

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not apply styles, because Bootstrap CSS resource is missing.
As you noticed, the class names are being applied by the `Alert` component correctly. 
Finally, the class names do not apply the correct styles, because Bootstrap CSS resource is missing.

A minimum viable fix to the situation is to import the minified Bootstrap CSS:

**1. install Bootstrap library** `yarn install bootstrap`

**2. add minified bootstrap CSS in your index.js** from node_modules folder after step 1

Let's also change your Alert component import to import only Alert functionality, not the full react-bootstrap library in its entirety.

Here is an example with your implementation, importing only Alert component:

```
index.js
```

--

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Alert from 'react-bootstrap/Alert'

class Error extends Component {
  render() {
    const { errorText } = this.props;
    return (
        <Alert bsStyle="warning" className="error-container">
          <div className="error-msg">{errorText}</div>
        </Alert>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try it after adding this code to your webpack.config.js

      {
                 test: /(\.css|\.scss)$/,
                loader: 'style-loader!css-loader?sourceMap&modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!sass-loader?sourceMap'
            }
```